# php failed to connect to mongodb socket

Tags: php, sockets, mongodb

just set up a fresh development ubuntu 13.04 server with nginx, php-fpm, and mongodb. The following line of code kills all of my scripts that were running great on a production ubuntu 12.10 server

```
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://user:pass@/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock/database");
```

error

> **Warning**:  MongoClient::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses:
> getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in
> **/var/www/app/php/db.php** on line **4**
>  
> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException'
> with message 'Failed to connect to: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock:0:
> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not
> known' in /var/www/app/php/db.php:4 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /var/www/app/php/db.php(4): MongoClient->__construct('mongodb://app...')
>
> ## 1 /var/www/app/admin/loggedin.php(3): require('/var/www/app...')
>
> ## 2 /var/www/app/admin/index.php(1): require('/var/www/app...')
>
> ## 3 {main}   thrown in **/var/www/app/php/db.php** on line **4**

I've been toying with this for a day and half and can't figure it out. It works when I connect to localhost but I'd really prefer sockets. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The PHP driver does not support passing in the credentials as part of the URI when connecting over Unix Domain Sockets.

You need to pass in the username and password in the $options array (2nd argument).

Comment: Actually, thats not true. We do support that - you are probably running into a bug PHP-846 that was fixed in 1.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04, Php 5.59, MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9

I got mine to work by passing the following:

I had to change my connection from `$m = new Mongo(); // connect` to `$m = new Mongo("mongodb://127.0.0.1"); // connect`

For some reason it appears that the /etc/hosts file stopped being called localhost for 127.0.0.1 which was throwing off the default mongodb connector so I had to be explicit. Sigh.